# How to fill bars with custom svg instead of a plain color in ngx-charts?

Tags: angular, svg, ngx-charts

I was trying to build a pattern as shown in below Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u2stx8

In the above Stackblitz I was not using any external library other than Angular.

I recently came across this beautiful library called **ngx-charts** which simplifies the work a lot while building complex charts.

It came up with several customising options such as adjusting [Width, Height], Legend Position, Custom Color Scheme etc.,

However, I still couldn't figure if there is an easy way to replace the color schemes with an SVG just like I did it above,

This is how patterns are currently shown:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-nchtrk

Can I fill the solid colors with SVGs?

Comment: no easy way i guess... going through this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878582/fill-a-svg-path-with-a-full-background-image) i was able to insert components (using inspect element) to get what you wanted...

Comment: That is in svg. Not ngx-charts.  The question here is about ngx-charts.

Comment: Yes yes, do inspect element with ngx-charts and this would work for you

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't fill the bars with a custom svg pattern without creating your own custom bar chart type.

The out-of-the-box bar chart configuration does let you use gradient colors within a bar, but doesn't allow for a custom svg.  (See the code here https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/src/bar-chart/bar.component.ts  Lines 26-36 are the svg bar definition.)